# SQL: A Grouping and Counting puzzle

Tags: sql, join, group-by, count

Here is a sample list of users and the station/time they start their transit journey on and the station/time they end:

```
user    Ststation   Starttime   endstation  endtime
bgh567  StationA    5:00:00     StationB    7:00:00
abc645  StationD    4:00:00     StationX    4:15:00
yh564   StationG    2:00:00     StationA    17:00:00
Yghf78  StationB    6:00:00     StationC    2:45:00
```

... this list is MUCH longer and throughout the day.

My goal is to get a count per station of the amount of users that started and ended their journey for each station in 15 minute intervals.  So the result would look like this (the counts ive made are samples and do not represent the sample tables in this post):

```
Time    Station     Enter   Exit
2:00:00 StationA    1      0
2:15:00 StationA    58     23
2:45:00 StationA    36     78
3:00:00 StationA    0      76
```

... and so on for the rest of the day. And then when StationA was finished StationB would be calculated and so on.

I've been able to get each respective count with queries like this:

```
SELECT starttime, ststation, COUNT(user) as count_enter
  FROM sourcetable 
  GROUP BY starttime, ststation 
  ORDER BY ststation, starttime
```

And a similar one for the exit counts.  But I am running into issues joining them together to create the end result above.  I'm doing this in Spark SQL but if I understand the methodology I can tailor any response to my environment.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something actually descriptive of the problem you're having or question you're asking. The title should be clear enough to be of use to future users here who are scanning a list of search results for a solution to a problem. Yours does not provide any useful information in that regard. Thanks.

Comment: And add your RDBMS tag plz!

Comment: Date/time functions are notoriously database-dependent.  Without a database tag, it is not really feasible to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is query for `Oracle`. Change functions used to your corresponding RDBMS:

```
WITH table_name AS 
(
    SELECT 'bgh567' AS user_name, 'StationA' AS station, sysdate + 1/(24*60) AS starttime, 'StationB' AS endstation, sysdate + 18/(24*60) AS endtime FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'abc645'AS user_name , 'StationD' AS station, sysdate + 15/(24*60) AS starttime, 'StationX' AS endstation, sysdate + 17/(24*60) AS endtime FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'yh564' AS user_name , 'StationG' AS station, sysdate + 12/(24*60) AS starttime, 'StationA' AS endstation, sysdate + 28/(24*60) AS endtime FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Yghf78'AS user_name , 'StationB' AS station, sysdate + 13/(24*60) AS starttime, 'StationC' AS endstation, sysdate + 19/(24*60) AS endtime FROM dual 
)
, enter_table AS
(
    SELECT 
        TO_CHAR(starttime, 'yyyy/mm/dd') || ' ' || TO_CHAR(starttime, 'hh24') 
            || ':' || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(TO_CHAR(starttime, 'MI') / 15) * 15, 'FM00') 
            || ':00' AS time_interval,
        station,
        COUNT(*) AS enter
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(starttime, 'yyyy/mm/dd'),
        TO_CHAR(starttime, 'hh24'),
        FLOOR(TO_CHAR(starttime, 'MI') / 15),
        station
)
, exit_table AS
(
    SELECT 
        TO_CHAR(endtime, 'yyyy/mm/dd') || ' ' || TO_CHAR(endtime, 'hh24') 
            || ':' || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(TO_CHAR(endtime, 'MI') / 15) * 15, 'FM00') 
            || ':00' AS time_interval,
        endstation AS station,
        COUNT(*) AS exit
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(endtime, 'yyyy/mm/dd'),
        TO_CHAR(endtime, 'hh24'),
        FLOOR(TO_CHAR(endtime, 'MI') / 15),
        endstation
)

SELECT
    COALESCE(e.time_interval, ex.time_interval) AS time_interval, 
    COALESCE(e.station, ex.station) AS station,
    COALESCE(e.enter, 0) AS enter,
    COALESCE(ex.exit , 0) AS exit 
FROM enter_table e
FULL OUTER JOIN exit_table ex
ON e.time_interval = ex.time_interval
    AND e.station = ex.station
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: Hey Pham thanks so much!  Actually I figured it out this morning with the same approach as you did here!  Once I discovered the COALESCE function it was pretty straightforward.